# Filebeat : find number of running harvester/s?

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

How to check how many harvester/s running at a given moment of time (in Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

For Filebeat 5.x (this is changing in 6.x), you can start Filebeat with an additional CLI flag to enable a metrics endpoint that can be queried over HTTP. One of the metrics returned in the JSON response object is [filebeat.harvester.running](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/5.4/filebeat/harvester/log.go#L26).

To test this you can start Filebeat in the foreground with the additional `-httpprof` flag.

`sudo filebeat.sh -e -httpprof localhost:9090`

Then request the metrics with `curl`.

`curl http://localhost:9090/debug/vars`